Vertical gaps between table cells and their contents
I have a tabular layout which contains graphical contents. I understand that using tables for layout is no longer a best practice, but I'm exploring this approach for educational purposes and to understand why this specific issue occurs: despite setting all relevant margins, paddings, and border-spacing to zero, a small gap remains between the bottom borders of the table cells and their contents.
I've inspected the code with developer tools, which indicate that the height of the table cells is larger than the contents, but provides no clues as to why.
Here's the code:


body{
   margin: 40px;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

table, tr, td {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

tr, td {
    border: 0px;
}


.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0;
}

.box-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-red{
    background-color: red;
}

.box-blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.box-maroon{
    background-color: maroon;
}

.box-violet{
    background-color: violet;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles-teste01.css"> -->
</head>

<body>

    <table role="presentation">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="box box-blue"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="box box-maroon"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="box box-red"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="box box-violet"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>

</html>



The snippet shows that all proper margins, borders and paddings are set to zero. The table's border-spacing is also zeroed - with no effect though, the annoying bottom gap survives no matter what I do. Inspecting the code with dev tools is of little help since it says that the height of the table cells are larger than their contents, but doesn't explain why this is happening.
If I change the value of the divs' display to "block", the gap disappears. According to an expert (ChatGPT), this works because the issue could be related to "how inline-block elements behave inside table cells. They can sometimes introduce whitespace or gaps due to the way they are rendered, often because of baseline alignment."
This explanation is wonderful, but does not really solve the issue: if I use img elements instead of divs, the gaps return - even if the imgs' display is set to "block" (p.s.: my divs' display had been set to "inline-block" to simulate the img behavior in my tests).
So, I have two questions:

Why changing the divs' display from "inline-block" to "block" makes the gaps disappear?
Why changing the imgs' display from "inline-block" to "block" does NOT make the gaps disappear like occurs with the divs?

Hope you folks can shed some light on that.

When div elements are set to inline-block, they behave like text characters, meaning they respect white space around them, including spaces, newlines, and tabs in the HTML code. This can create gaps between inline-block elements.
when you change an img element's display to block, the gaps may persist due to the default alignment of images. By default, images are aligned to the baseline of the text, leaving some space beneath them reserved for descenders. This space remains even when the image is displayed as a block element.

@AntonijaŠimić, this looks odd to me. I've tried to change my img's vertical alignment with no result - so, there is no way of eliminating those gaps?
